# Declaration Terminated Incorrectly

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, borland-c++

The full code is correct but I'm getting only this one error on line 28 which is: `declaration terminated incorrectly`.

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream.h>
class Rail
{
private:
char GetYN();
struct Train
{
    int tno, nop;
    char tname[50];
    char dest[50];
    float dist, fare;
}t;
public:
void Input();
void CreateFile();
void Display();
void Search();
void Modify();
void Delete();
void AddRecord();
}R;
void introduction();
{                         \\This is where the error is (error: declaration terminated incorrectly)
clrscr()
cout << "\n\n";
cout << "\t  =============================================================\n";
cout << "\t  **                                                         **\n";
cout << "\t  **                       WELCOME TO                        **\n";
cout << "\t  **                         METRO                           **\n";
cout << "\t  **               RAILWAY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM                 **\n";
cout << "\t  **                                                         **\n";
cout << "\t  ** PROGRAMMED BY:-                                         **\n";
cout << "\t  ** ----------------                                        **\n";
cout << "\t  **             Waqar                                       **\n";
cout << "\t  **                                                         **\n";
cout << "\t  **             Std: XII  Div: A                            **\n";
cout << "\t  **                                                         **\n";
cout << "\t  **             INDIAN CENTRAL SCHOOL                       **\n";
cout << "\t  **             KUWAIT                                      **\n";
cout << "\t  **                                                         **\n";
cout << "\t  =============================================================\n";
cout << "\n\n\t Press any key to view the Main Menu.";
getch();
}
char Rail::GetYN()
{
char ch;
do
{
    ch = getch();
} while ((ch != 'Y'&&ch != 'y') && (ch != 'N'&&ch != 'n'))
    return ch;
}

void Rail::Input()
{
cout << "\nEnter the train number: ";
cin >> t.tno;
cout << "\nEnter the no of pasengers: ";
cin >> t.nop;
cout << "\nEnter the train name: ";
gets(t.tname);
cout << "\nEnter the destination: ";
gets(t.dest);
cout << "\nEnter the distance: ";
cin >> t.dist;
cout << "\nEnter the fare: ";
cin >> t.fare;
}

void Rail::CreateFile()
{
char ContinueYN;
fstream DataFile;
DataFile.open("Train.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
do
{
    clrscr()
    Input;
    DataFile.write((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
    cout << "\nDo you want to enter another record [y/n]";
    ContinueYN = GetYN();
} while (ContinueYN == 'y' || ContinueYN == 'Y');
DataFile.close();
}

void Rail::Display()
{
fstream DataFile;
DataFile.open("Train.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
DataFile.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
clrscr()

while (!DataFile.eof())
{
    cout << "\nTrain no: " << t.tno;
    cout << "\nNo of Passengers: " << t.nop;
    cout << "\nTrain name: " << t.tname;
    cout << "\nDestination: " << t.dest;
    cout << "\nDistance: " << t.dist;
    cout << "\nFare: " << t.fare;
    cout << "\n\n ";

    cout << "\nPress any key to continue..";
    getch();
    clrscr();
    DataFile.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
}
DataFile.close();
}

void Rail::Search()
{
int IdToSearchFor, found = 0;
clrscr()
cout << "\nEnter the train number to be searched: ";
cin >> IdToSearchFor;

fstream DataFile;
DataFile.open("Train.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
do
{
    DataFile.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
    if (t.tno == IdToSearchFor)
    {
        cout << "\nNo. of Passengers: " << t.nop;
        cout << "\nTrain name: " << t.tname;
        cout << "\nDestination: " << t.dest;
        cout << "\nDistance: " << t.dist;
        cout << "\nFare: " << t.fare;
        cout << "\n\n";
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
} while (!DataFile.eof());
if (found == 0)
{
    cout << "\nRecord not found!";
}
cout << "\nPress any key to continue.";
getch();
}

void Rail::Modify()
{
fstream DataFileo;
int IdToSearchFor, found = 0;
char ModifyYesNo;

clrscr()
    cout << "\nEnter train number of train whose details you want to modify: ";
cin >> IdToSearchFor;
fstream DataFilei;
DataFilei.open("Train.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
do
{
    DataFilei.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
    if (t.tno == IdToSearchFor)
    {
        found = 1;
        cout << "\nNo. of Passengers: " << t.nop;
        cout << "\nTrain Name: " << t.tname;
        cout << "\nDesitnation: " << t.dest;
        cout << "\nDistance: " << t.dist;
        cout << "\nFare: " << t.fare;
        cout << "\n\n";
        cout << "Do you want to Modify the above record[Y/N]:";
        ModifyYesNo = GetYN();
        if (ModifyYesNo == 'y' || ModifyYesNo == 'Y')
        {
            DataFileo.open("Train.dat", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::in)


                cout << "Do you want to modify the train name[y/n]";
            ModifyYesNo = GetYN();
            if (ModifyYesNo == 'y' || ModifyYesNo == 'Y')
            {
                cout << "\nEnter the name of the train: ";
                gets(t.tname);
            }

            cout << "Do you want to modify the Destination[y/n]";
            ModifyYesNo = GetYN();
            if (ModifyYesNo == 'y' || ModifyYesNo == 'Y')
            {
                cout << "\nEnter new destination: ";
                gets(t.dest);
            }

            cout << "Do you want to modify the Distance[y/n]";
            ModifyYesNo = GetYN();
            if (ModifyYesNo == 'y' || ModifyYesNo == 'Y')
            {
                cout << "\nEnter the new distance: ";
                cin >> t.dist;
            }

            cout << "Do you want to modify the Fare[y/n]";
            ModifyYesNo = GetYN();
            if (ModifyYesNo == 'y' || ModifyYesNo == 'Y')
            {
                cout << "\nEnter the new fare: ";
                cin >> t.fare;
            }

            DataFileo.write((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
            break;
        }
    }
} while (!DataFilei.eof());

if (found == 0)
{
    cout << "\nRecord not found!";
    DataFilei.close();
    DataFileo.close();
    cout << "\nPress any key to continue.";
    getch();
}
}
void Rail::AddRecord()
{
fstream DataFile;
DataFile.open("Train.dat", ios::app | ios::binary);

char ContinueYN = 'N';
do
{
    clrscr()
    cout << "\nEnter the train number: ";
    cin >> t.tno;
    cout << "\nEnter the no of pasengers: ";
    cin >> t.nop;
    cout << "\nEnter the train name: ";
    gets(t.tname);
    cout << "\nEnter the destination: ";
    gets(t.dest);
    cout << "\nEnter the distance: ";
    cin >> t.dist;
    cout << "\nEnter the fare: ";
    cin >> t.fare;

    DataFile.write((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
    cout << "\nDo you want to enter another record[y/n]";
    ContinueYN = GetYN();
    system("cls");
} while (ContinueYN == 'Y' || ContinueYN == 'y')
    DataFile.close();
}
void Rail::Delete()
{
fstream DataFilei;
fstream DataFileo;

int IdToSearchFor, found = 0;
char ModifyYesNo;

clrscr()
cout << "\nEnter the train no of the record to delete: ";
cin >> IdToSearchFor;
DataFilei.open("Train.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
DataFile.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));

while (!DataFilei.eof())
{
    if (t.tno == IdToSearchFor)
    {
        cout << "\nNo. of Passengers: " << t.nop;
        cout << "\nTrain name: " << t.tname;
        cout << "\nDestination: " << t.dest;
        cout << "\nDistance: " << t.dist;
        cout << "\nFare: " << t.fare;
        cout << "\n\n";
        cout << "Do you want to Delete the above record[y/n]:";
        ModifyYesNo = GetYN();
        found = 1;
    }
    DataFilei.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
}
if (found == 0)
{
    cout << "Record not found!";
    cout << "\nPress any key to continue.";
    getch();
}
DataFilei.close();

if (ModifyYesNo == 'Y' || ModifyYesNo == 'y')
{
    DataFilei.open("Train.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    DataFileo.open("Temp.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
    DataFilei.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));

    while (!DataFile.eof())
    {
        if (t.tno != IdToSearchFor)
            DataFileo.write((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
        DataFilei.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
    }
    DataFileo.close();
    DataFilei.close();
    DataFileo.open("Temp.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    DataFilei.open("Train.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
    while (!DataFile.eof())
    {
        DataFileo.write((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
        DataFilei.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
    }
    DataFileo.close();
    DataFilei.close();
}
}

void main()
{
introduction();
clrscr()
int choice;
do
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\tMain Menu\n";
    cout << "\t1. Create a new Flight file\n";
    cout << "\t2. Display Flight record\n";
    cout << "\t3. Search in Flight record\n";
    cout << "\t4. Add record\n";
    cout << "\t5. Delete record\n";
    cout << "\t6. Modify record\n";
    cout << "\t7. Exit\n\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:R.CreateFile();
        break;
    case 2:R.Display();
        break;
    case 3:R.Search();
        break;
    case 4:R.AddRecord();
        break;
    case 5:R.Delete();
        break;
    case 6:R.Modify();
        break;
    }
} while (choice != 7);
}
```

This code was written in turbo c++ 4.5.

What is wrong with it ?

Comment: Your code needs to be **here**, in your question itself, and not in an external location. Please [edit] to provide it, and include the **exact error message** you're receiving at the same time.

Comment: First and foremost: welcome to SO! Your question is definitely "within scope", however we prefer that you put your code here. If your code is removed from the external site in the future, your question won't make sense.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here as I mentioned before I'll edit my question and add my code here.

Comment: I'm surprised that you managed to write all that code and were still not able to spot the trivial syntax error with a clear error message.

Comment: _"The full code is correct"_ - obviously it's not if you're getting errors.

Comment: Haha..I actually meant the rest of the code...Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Line 27/28 is

```
void introduction();
{
```

Remove the `;` and get rid of TurboC++.

TurboC++ 4.5 is from about 1993 (C++ wasn´t even standardized before 1998,
and recently (2011+) there a big changes again). Do yourself a favor and switch.
GCC or Clang, or (if you don´t need very new features) VS.

Maybe it helps if I say that this code generates nearly ~370 lines
of errors (after correcting the includes, because it won´t compile
anything otherwise). Newest G++ with -std=c++1y, Wall and Wextra

Comment: After removing that now I have more 15 errors.

All errors are missing semi-colon(;). Idk why it is giving these errors because there are (;) present over there.

For turbo c++ I actually did this in visual studio and it was giving me a lot of errors because the code is old and visual studio don't recognize some of the code. I had to use turbo because my school teaches old c++.

Comment: Let me ask you something: If you´ve learned the old C++, what will you do then? Nothing. C++ of dinosaur age and/or non-standard won´t help you today. Get GCC or Clang (the compilers which adapted current developments, VS is some years late) and hope that your teacher will accept modern C++ too. Else, with TurboC++, learning C++ makes no sense.

Comment: Ok I removed those silly errors now there are just 2 errors left.

line 84: Member Function must be called or its address taken in function Rail::CreateFile()


line 267: Undefined symbol 'DataFile" in function Rail::Delete()

Comment: @MohammadWaqar:  First of all, you need to stop thinking your code is perfect.  If you treat it like it may not be correct, then you may start to find the problems in it.  For example, the line `clrscr()` **clearly** does not have a semicolon on it.  Also, it's not a personal failing to write code that isn't correct the first time.  That's normal.

Comment: I didn't notice that sorry I made the correction to the code.

Comment: @deviantfan The school won't change because honestly everything sucks in this school they still teach about how to use windows 98 to students who are in 8th grade. I try to learn coding on my own but I don't get time mostly because of other projects or subjects.

Comment: @MohammadWaqar: Well, I can´t help you to change the school. I know there are many like that (country doesn´t matter), but TurboC++ 4.5 is from about 1993 (C++ wasn´t even standardized before 1998, and recently (2011+) there a big changes again). Do yourself a favor...

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping I removed the errors now the code is working.